# Is there a way to have an IF statement based on a data validation list value in a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

In column P, I have a drop down list, the code to add that looks like this for every new worksheet I create.

```
lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

With Range("P2:P" & lastrow).Validation
 .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Yes,No,N/A"
 .IgnoreBlank = True
 .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

In column Q I want another drop down list to populate based on specific values the user inputs from column P.

For example, if the user chooses `No` in column P, I want only values `value 1` or `value 2` to populate in that row of column Q. If the user chooses `Yes` in column P, I want only values `value 3` or `value 4` to populate in column Q.

I know I'd need to declare something like this above:

```
Dim ActionRow As Long

Dim colAction As Long
colAction = 16

For ActionRow = 2 To 500 ' Wb.Worksheet("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If .Cells(ActionRow, 16).Value = "No" Then
    ADD DROP DOWN LIST VALUES 1 & 2
Next ActionRow
```

can anyone help me revise this, or is this not possible without data already being in the column?

Comment: You can use the same code to add the validation lists, but you will probably want to put it in a change event so it's triggered when col P is changed. Or see eg https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: dependent drop down lists are way to go (see link from @SJR). why use code when you don't have to?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, this will add validation lists to Column Q depending on values selected on Column P:

```
Sub foo()
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("P2:P" & lastrow).Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Yes,No,N/A"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 16 And Target.Value = "No" Then
    With Range("Q" & Target.Row).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="value 1, value 2"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With
ElseIf Target.Column = 16 And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    With Range("Q" & Target.Row).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="value 3, value 4"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this ran through just fine, but doesn't create a data validation list once I open the file. Is this because there is no current value in column P until the user selects an item off the list? The current value stays blank until inputted

Comment: @nicklanta the first Sub will create the Data Validation List for Column P, and the Worksheet_Change Sub will make it so that when the user selects something from the list in Column P, the Data Validation List on Column Q will be generated so the user can select from it accordingly. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I understand the process, but it's not populating a data validation list in column Q, rows 2 & lastrow

Comment: it completely skips through he Private sub in the module

Comment: @nicklanta The values don't populate Column Q, but they are available to be selected by the user. Would you be able to share your workbook? Maybe upload to something like Google Drive/Dropbox and comment a link to it here, so I can have a look at it? As the answer I provided does work when I'm testing...